# bash script that's inside a c++ program doesn't work correctly after a while

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am using a Raspberry Pi4 with `Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

I have a service that starts a C++ program. This program starts a script, reads content from some files and outputs information on a RGB LED Display.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(head -n 1 /var/www/html/configuration.txt)
file=/var/www/html/4panel/url_response.txt
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    wget -q -i $line -O $file
    chown pi:pi $file
else
    echo > $file
    chown pi:pi $file 
fi
```

I need to do `wget` periodically because that URL sends the information in real-time and I need to output it on the Display. In order to do this, I call this script from inside a `while()` loop in the C++ program with:

```
system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");
```

But after some time `url_response.txt` gets empty and remains empty until I restart the service. Meaning that the script isn't working properly.

This is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=PPD_Display service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

A weird thing that I've noticed is that the script runs two times, and maybe that's why it stops working properly:

```
root     26849  0.0  0.0   1940   364 ?        S    12:55   0:00 sh -c /var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh
root     26850  0.0  0.1   7808  2580 ?        S    12:55   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh
```

And if that is not the problem, then why does the script just stops working correctly if the service is still running ?

## Update 1:

After a day of monitoring it I've noticed that the service freezes.
I have noticed this by using `journalctl -e -u DisplayM` which will return the latest log of that respective service. In this case the latest entry marks the time when the service freezes. I have placed some `std::cout` throughout the program and it seems that it stops at `system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");`.

## Update 2:

The script's `if/else` logic is that if it doesn't find the file, it should create an empty one so that on the next loop it can do a `wget` and get the latest information. I thought of it to be kind of a fail safe. The `url_response.txt` file always needs to exist.

I have dropped the `chown pi:pi $file` that comes after the `wget`, because it seemed redundant.
The script looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(head -n 1 /var/www/html/configuration.txt)
file=/var/www/html/4panel/url_response.txt
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    wget_output=$(wget -q -i "$line" -O $file --timeout=2)
    echo "$?"
else
    echo > $file
    chown pi:pi $file 
fi
```

Also, by changing the wget line from this:

```
wget -q -i $line -O $file
```

to this:

```
wget_output=$(wget -q -i "$line" -O $file --timeout=2)
```

and the call of the script from:

```
system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");
```

to:

```
std::cout<<"System return value: "<<system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh")<<std::endl;
```

the service hasn't frozen in over 12 hours. It worked without any problem except some rare `wget` return values of 4 which mean `network failure`, which I guess are pretty normal.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) has a few things to say about the script. But why use a Bash script at all for something C++ could do?!

Comment: The two processes are because `system` creates a process running `sh`.  That invokes your script - which creates a sub-process running bash.  Nothing to worry about.  (You could skip the two processes with `system("exec /bin/bash /var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");` - but there is no point.

Comment: @Biffen I think I found it easier ?! I don't really know.

Comment: @MartinBonner Ok. That makes some sense. Then why do you think it stops working correctly after a while ?

Comment: No idea, which is why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer.  Sorry.  (Aside: Anything which provokes "hmm, that's odd" is a *really*, *really* good place to look for a source of bugs - sadly, in this case the extra process isn't actually all that odd.)

Comment: Your `if/else` logic doesn't make sense to me. `if $file exists` then overwrite the existing file with a call to `curl -O ...` and change its ownership. ELSE `$file doesn't exist`, so make an empty file and change it's ownership. It's not clear why you're doing it this way, maybe please update your Q describing your use-case for this logic (and NOT reply in comments). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Done ! I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Well it seems you've solved your problem. Still not sure why you're creating an empty `$file`, only to overwrite it on the next run AND then only to continue overwriting it on each run after that. Why the test at all, just run `curl -i .. -l $file ..` each time. But, glad you solved it. In the future, it is better S.O. etiquite to leave your Q in it's original(ish) state and write an answer which you can accept after 48? hrs and gain valuable reputation points! ;-) Good luck.